The StartJobAttempt<StartJobAttempt> (Event) execution faulted
I'm using MassTransit 8.25.0 on .NET 8.
I have a Windows service with a scheduler and a job consumer. Can't figure out how to queue a job, IPublishEndpoint from example is a scoped service, so I can't inject it.
My attempts

clientFactory.CreateRequestClient

public class ImportScheduler(
    IScheduleConfig<ImportScheduler> config,
    ILogger<ImportScheduler> logger,
    IClientFactory clientFactory)
    : CronJobService(config.CronExpression, config.TimeZoneInfo, logger)
{
    protected override async Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var requestClient = clientFactory.CreateRequestClient<ImportRequested>();

        var jobId = NewId.Next();
        await requestClient.GetResponse<JobSubmissionAccepted>(new ImportRequested(
            jobId.ToGuid(),
            Guid.Parse("7718D173-1F3F-4F8C-B282-5B5A1C183BCE")), cancellationToken);
    }
}

This throws an error:

MassTransit.EventExecutionException: The StartJobAttempt (Event) execution faulted
MassTransit.PayloadNotFoundException: The payload was not found: MassTransit.MessageSchedulerContext


Tried to create IPublishEndpoint from IBus with GetPublishSendEndpoint, got ISendEndpoint

public class ImportScheduler(
    IScheduleConfig<ImportScheduler> config,
    ILogger<ImportScheduler> logger,
    IBus bus)
    : CronJobService(config.CronExpression, config.TimeZoneInfo, logger)
{
    protected override async Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var publishEndpoint = await bus.GetPublishSendEndpoint<SubmitJob<ImportRequested>>();

        var jobId = NewId.Next();
        await publishEndpoint.Send(new
        {
            JobId = jobId,
            Job = new ImportRequested(
                jobId.ToGuid(),
                Guid.Parse("7718D173-1F3F-4F8C-B282-5B5A1C183BCE"))
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}


Used bus.Publish<SubmitJob<ImportRequested>> directly, but got error similar to the first one.

Also I got an error below, but not exactly sure where it comes from

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at MassTransit.ExceptionInfoException..ctor(ExceptionInfo exceptionInfo) in //src/MassTransit.Abstractions/Exceptions/ExceptionInfoException.cs:line 14
at MassTransit.JobService.FinalizeJobConsumer1.Consume(ConsumeContext1 context) in //src/MassTransit/JobService/JobService/FinalizeJobConsumer.cs:line 43
at MassTransit.Middleware.MethodConsumerMessageFilter2.MassTransit.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer,TMessage>>.Send(ConsumerConsumeContext2 context, IPipe1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/MethodConsumerMessageFilter.cs:line 28    at MassTransit.Configuration.PipeConfigurator1.LastPipe.Send(TContext context) in //src/MassTransit.Abstractions/Middleware/Configuration/PipeBuilder.cs:line 123
at MassTransit.Consumer.DelegateConsumerFactory1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext1 context, IPipe1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Consumers/Consumer/DelegateConsumerFactory.cs:line 29     at MassTransit.Consumer.DelegateConsumerFactory1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext1 context, IPipe1 next) in //src/MassTransit/Consumers/Consumer/DelegateConsumerFactory.cs:line 39
at MassTransit.Middleware.ConsumerMessageFilter2.MassTransit.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/ConsumerMessageFilter.cs:line 48

Configuration
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    // some consumers

    x.AddConsumer<ImportConsumer>(cc =>
    {
        cc.Options<JobOptions<ImportRequested>>(xx =>
            xx.SetRetry(r => r.None()).SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromHours(3)).SetConcurrentJobLimit(1));
    });

    x.SetJobConsumerOptions();
    x.AddJobSagaStateMachines();
    x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();

    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureServiceBus"));

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

If I change my consumer from IJobConsumer to IConsumer, I am able to queue it using IBus.Publish

First, you can simply your job submission:
public class ImportScheduler(
    IScheduleConfig<ImportScheduler> config,
    ILogger<ImportScheduler> logger,
    IBus bus)
    : CronJobService(config.CronExpression, config.TimeZoneInfo, logger)
{
    protected override async Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var jobId = NewId.Next();
        await bus.Publish<SubmitJob<ImportRequested>>(new
        {
            JobId = jobId,
            Job = new ImportRequested(
                jobId.ToGuid(),
                Guid.Parse("7718D173-1F3F-4F8C-B282-5B5A1C183BCE"))
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}

And your bus configuration is missing the scheduler.
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    // some consumers

    x.AddConsumer<ImportConsumer>(cc =>
    {
        cc.Options<JobOptions<ImportRequested>>(xx =>
            xx.SetRetry(r => r.None()).SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromHours(3)).SetConcurrentJobLimit(1));
    });

    x.SetJobConsumerOptions();
    x.AddJobSagaStateMachines();
    x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();

    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureServiceBus"));

        cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

This is all demonstrated in the sample as well.

thanks, I figured it out slightly differently and posted it now, not sure if it is better or worse. I think in my case it also complained about job class - a record with primary constructor (no parameter-less constructor)

Completely forgot I could create scope inside of singleton and also included the missing lines from the demo in configuration
public class ImportScheduler(
    IScheduleConfig<ImportScheduler> config,
    ILogger<ImportScheduler> logger,
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    : CronJobService(config.CronExpression, config.TimeZoneInfo, logger)
{
    protected override async Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var jobId = NewId.NextGuid();
        using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var publishEndpoint = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPublishEndpoint>();

        await publishEndpoint.Publish<SubmitJob<ImportRequested>>(new
        {
            JobId = jobId,
            Job = new
            {
                Id = jobId,
                CustomerId = Guid.Parse("7718D173-1F3F-4F8C-B282-5B5A1C183BCE")
            }
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler(); // <------ added this

    // consumers

    x.AddConsumer<ImportConsumer>(cc =>
    {
        cc.Options<JobOptions<ImportRequested>>(xx =>
            xx.SetRetry(r => r.None()).SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromHours(3)).SetConcurrentJobLimit(1));
    });

    x.SetJobConsumerOptions();
    x.AddJobSagaStateMachines();
    x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();

    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler(); // <------- and this

        cfg.Host(configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureServiceBus"));

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});


Do NOT use this  cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler(); with Azure, use what I suggested. UseServiceBusMessageScheduler

There is an AddServiceBusMessageScheduler as well. But you're using service bus, it's scheduler is more advanced than just delayed.
